# How to send Google Maps location by SMS

Tags: android, google-maps, smsmanager

how do I assign a variable `LocationManager` in the text string of `SMSManager`?
I want to send the sms with coordinates as text message.

private LocationManager lm;
            private LocationListener locationListener;

```
    lm = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();   

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
             0, 
             0, 
            locationListener);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(

            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0, 
            locationListener);


btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendSMS("55565", "coords" );

        }
    });



 private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code to get the location.

Comment: hey @Simon .. i just did.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Was my code to send current location through email and sms Hope it helps :)
modify it according to your need

```
final LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    final LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

    final Location location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    mc=mapview.getController();
    mc.setZoom(18);
    mlo=new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapview);
    mapview.getOverlays().add(mlo);
    mapview.invalidate();   
    }




    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

    {

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location)
    {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }

    private void updateWithNewLocation(final Location location)
    {
    mapview=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    String latLongString;
    TextView myLocationText;
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    String addressString = "No address found";

    if ( location != null )
    {
    final double lat = location.getLatitude();
    final double lng = location.getLongitude();

    latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
    final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    final Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    final GeoPoint myLocation = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1000000), (int)(lng * 1000000));
    mapview.getController().animateTo(myLocation);
    mapview.getController().setCenter(myLocation);


    try
    {
    final List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 4);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if ( addresses.size() > 0 )
    {
        final Address address = addresses.get(0);
        for ( int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++ )
        {
            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
        }
        sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getCountryName());
    }
    addressString = sb.toString();
    }
    catch ( final IOException e )
    {
    }
    }
    else
    {
    latLongString = "No location found";
    }
    myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
    latLongString + "\n" + addressString);


    }





    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inf = getMenuInflater();
        inf.inflate(R.menu.newmenu, menu);
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String tv1; 
        TextView myLocationText;
        myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv1= myLocationText.getText().toString(); 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.msg:

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", tv1); 
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(sendIntent); 

    return(true);
    case R.id.email:
        /* Create the Intent */
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        /* Fill it with Data */
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to@email.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, tv1);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         return(true);
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
```

Comment: very nice bro, thanks... leveraging how to send the sms automatically instead by user command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620150/can-i-automatically-send-sms-without-the-user-need-to-approve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607361/android-send-sms-automatically-on-button-click